# How to save a dict after changes?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json file that can be updated from outside, but I also want to update it from inside so I need to load it everytime I want to access it (I can do that with `@property`).

But I want to save the changes I make inside the python script immediatly.
I also want to be able to create nested dicts and lists and save them if they change.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following functions to read and write your dict :

```
import json

def write_json(path,data):
    j = json.dumps(data)
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(j)


def read_json(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        return json.load(f)
```

Comment: Perhaps should use locking too.

Comment: I have already done that but his doesn't save after I edit the dictionnary